# RichTextBox text color

Tags: c#, forms, richtextbox

I created RichTextBox and I add this code:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //( )
        int selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        string helpText = richTextBox1.Text;
        int closerPos;

        for (int i = 0; i < helpText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (helpText[i] == '(')
            {
                selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
                closerPos = helpText.Substring(i).IndexOf(')') + i;

                helpText = helpText.Substring(i + 1, closerPos - i - 1);
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(i + 1, closerPos - i - 1);


                richTextBox1.Select(i + 1, 0);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                richTextBox1.SelectedText = helpText;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;


                helpText = richTextBox1.Text;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code should color the text between the ( ).
For example:

> "Hi (need to be colored) text (sdadsasd) "

the text between the ( ) need to be colored in red. but only the last text is colored. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the first paranthesis with that if condition.

Try splitting the text like `helpText.Split('(');`

Then iterate over it and do your logic.

Comment: Why do I need to split it?

Comment: You have to know how many () texts inside richtextbox's text. Actually your code finds first () then finishes. If you split it you can execute your logic for each () area.

Comment: Ok but it is still not explaning why this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this without moving byte by byte. You can try to do it using the IndexOf method.

This is something I was thinking of:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rbText = richTextBox1.Text;

    int position = 0;
    int startBrace = rbText.IndexOf('(', position) + 1;

    while (startBrace != -1)
    {
        position = rbText.IndexOf(')', startBrace);

        if (position != -1)
        {
             richTextBox1.Select(startBrace, position - startBrace);
             richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

             startBrace = rbText.IndexOf('(', position) + 1;
        }
        else
             break;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I haven't fully test this code.

Answer (score 0):

I already see a potential issue, helpText is being used as an array when it is only a single-variable string. Try breaking the entirety of helpText down into a char array, then iterating through that to find your brackets.